# Converting a hex string to base 64

Tags: python, python-3.x

This seems like it should be the simplest thing in the world, and there is also some questions regarding it on here, but none of them seem to work. In a lot of cases/answers, arguments aren't properly filled in, or answers just straight up don't work.

I have this super simple code, Where I take two chars, get their hex-values, and convert them to ints.
I then xor them, and convert the result to a hex. Now I just want to convert this output to a char again. This for some reason, is not a simple task:

```
h1 = int(hex(ord("c")),16)
h = int(hex(ord("5")), 16)

heks = hex(h ^ h1)
```

And here `heks` is `0x56`.
I now want the char value. I've tried this:
fu = base64.encode(heks)
Which doesnt work, since a argument is missing.

How do I get a char back?

**my other attempts**

I have also tried this function that I found:

```
def HS_to_bs4(string):
    decodedHexString = bytes.fromhex(string)
    bs4_encodedString =base64.b64encode(decodedHexString)
    return bs4_encodedString.decode()
```

It does'nt work either, it fails in the first line with

```
non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 1
```

**EDIT**
I realized I was doing too much work here, and simplified to this:

```
h1 = ord("c")
h = ord("8")
print(6^1)
heks = h ^ h1
print(heks)
print(chr(heks))
```

Where I can simply cast to a char, great.
But theres a tiny issue now.
the overall exercise that I'm doing, has to do with taking this string:

```
1c0111001f010100061a024b53535009181c
```

xor'ing it with this one:

```
686974207468652062756c6c277320657965
```

Which should produce this one:

```
746865206b696420646f6e277420706c6179
```

For numerical values, like `1` and `6`, this gives `7`, which fits.

But when I have chars, like `c` and `8`, I get `]`. Which doesnt really make sense to me, since it should really give me `4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `chr(heks)`. That usually converts ASCII indices to their corresponding characters.

At least according to your MRE, you don't actually need the `hex` of `h ^ h1`, so you can just call `char = chr(h ^ h1)`.

EDIT:

If you have two input strings and you need to xor them together, just do

```
A = "abc"
B = "def"

result = [chr(ord(a) ^ ord(b)) for a, b in zip(A, B)]
```

The `result` will then be another `str` and you should have no problems encoding it using `base64`.

If your input strings are actually not strings, but hexadecimal numbers, then you can convert them to numbers using `A = int(A, 16)`.
The code would then look this way:

```
A = "1c0111001f010100061a024b53535009181c"
B = "686974207468652062756c6c277320657965"

A = int(A, 16)
B = int(B, 16)

result = hex(A ^ B) # 0x746865206b696420646f6e277420706c6179
```

Comment: I added an edit with these changes. This does work, but the xor seems to give me wrong values?

Comment: @partyTuringFriend Ah, I get it. You don't need `hex` at all, if I understand correctly. You just need to `xor` the two things.

Comment: @partyTuringFriend Check out the new solution.

Comment: @partyTuringFriend By the way, all of this is compiled from two first-result-searches on stackoverflow. You'd save yourself a lot of time if you invested a bit more of it to searching c: